# Using Script Tags As A Template System

Tags: javascript, html, dom, template-engine

** **Revised** **

I made this basic example which I believe is evicence that JavaScript may be useful as it's own template engine:
http://jsfiddle.net/julienetienne/u6akrx7j/

```
<script>talk[0].text('Hello World!');</script>
```

It's just a simple example but as you can see there are many possibilities eg.

- It doesn't necessarily have to detect the tag nodes in that manner, it could do it by class, id. It is also possible to obtain the script node of the function,
- you could simply print variables like p('Page Title');
- A self closing list of elements could be similar to e.g. li('', menu);
- And you could clearly build up other complex data sets as you can with any other common template engine.

Before this edit I made the mistake of comparing it to PHP. I'm actually considering it more of an alternative to e.g. **handlebars**, **underscore**, **moustache**, **dust** and similar.

But before I get to excited I would really like to know if there are any issues in regards to using  in this way. (I'm not concerned with novice best practices).

The benefits of an organic template system seems quite apparent. The biggest advantage is that there is no syntax to learn and it's cleaner than seeing %{{foobar}}% like markings.

**Considering my example is just a tiny minimalistic concept, please tell me the drawbacks of a system like this compared to common template engines.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a PHP-style templating system, but it is apparently not:
In the fiddle the script parts could be written anywhere in the page.

The part that defines the position of the texts to be inserted into the DOM is defined by the line `var talk = document.getElementsByTagName('div');` and the structure of the HTML.

If you'd use more `div` than the ones already there the texts will appear at a totally different (and supposedly wrong) position.

The disavantage will thus be, that you can't use the system independently of the underlying markup. That makes it different from a use case in PHP, where you can echo the variables by defining their position in the markup.

Have a look at Angular or similar front end frameworks, if you are looking for a way how to implement a templating system.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I've realized my question wasn't specific enough, I will make some edits as I admit I am totally unclear of what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: Maybe the biggest drawback is, that there are no advantages. I still don't understand how you would like to define the markers. Where is the difference to regular javascript, besides that your are splitting your script into multiple parts... which isn't actually an advantage. 

You might need to show a concept, where the script itself is aware of it's parent script container. I think it's impossible though.

Comment: Slight modification: https://jsfiddle.net/julienetienne/v7Lbu0u4/3/

It is possible to get the parent node, I tired it from an SO answer and it worked but I'm conflicted, I may try it again.

The fact that it is just JavaScript is the whole purpose, no template mark-up can be as powerful as JS.

The splitting serves the purpose of readability. It's useless otherwise.

1 show stopper is separating the template from the data. If I parse the html via ajax the script functionality won't work. Which means it seems  better for server rendering not client.

Comment: It looks a lot more promising like this, but I still think the script tags are not necessary, as you are still working with query selectors. It would be enough, to set ids (or any other attribute) in the div. I made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/q2uuef8m/1

I see few disadvantages in the <script> concept: 1. it's a lot to write. In some other template languages you just write {{ namespace.property }} 2. It's not neccessary to use the script tags. if you have the content coming from a central position like in your `var text`. 3. If you render server-side, why not render the actual values?

Comment: Great that has helped, it shows separation of data, the template and the logic. I know this is really basic stuff but many temp' engines are overkill and are not really logic-less.

I believe a template framework via the data-* attribute may be a great way to do things like add tittles, create complex list, tables and so on. eg., < ul data-fooBar="li: for fruits in basket > as a basic example.

I think it's best done on the client side as It saves requests. I think I have the right idea now, thanks for the example

Comment: If you do something open source, let me know. I am interested to follow (an possibly contribute?) your idea. A leight-weight template framework with angular-like syntax could be interesting. as long as it doesn't try to solve to many problems.

Comment: Definitely, I'll let you know when for sure thanks. It will be open source and quite light weight. The main goal is to really see if there's a more native way to do templates, won't be re-inventing the wheel here ;)